# Conditionals not being tested properly

Tags: bash, syntax

I've got this script that runs every time my Ubuntu machine wakes up and goes to sleep.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want before suspend here, e.g.:
  echo "we are suspending at $(date)..." > /home/albin/stuff/suspend_test
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want after resume here, e.g.:
  echo "...and we are back from $(date)" >> /home/albin/stuff/suspend_test
else
  echo ".2..neither pre or post . $1 .   $(date)" >> /home/albin/stuff/suspend_test
fi
```

This is found in the output file:

```
.2..neither pre or post . pre .   tis 11 sep 2018 20:44:42 CEST
.2..neither pre or post . post .   tis 11 sep 2018 20:45:06 CEST
.2..neither pre or post . pre .   tis 11 sep 2018 22:12:52 CEST
.2..neither pre or post . post .   ons 12 sep 2018 06:55:21 CEST
.2..neither pre or post . pre .   ons 12 sep 2018 06:55:22 CEST
.2..neither pre or post . post .   ons 12 sep 2018 06:55:43 CEST
.2..neither pre or post . pre .   ons 12 sep 2018 07:13:28 CEST
.2..neither pre or post . post .   ons 12 sep 2018 07:14:00 CEST
```

---

I've checked multiple guides on how to write bash conditionals without finding any issues. The $1 variable is available but ignored in the if statements

Comment: What does `echo "$1"` show?  As an aside, why are you tagging this as bash while your script has `#!/bin/sh` in the shebang line?

Comment: Yea, that was the problem, thinking I was using bash when I was using sh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `==` instead of `=` inside `[ ]`, but that's a bashism. Recent versions of Ubuntu use dash as /bin/sh, and it does not support `==`; it gets an error, which is interpreted as the test failing:

```
$ if [ foo == foo ]; then echo "The strings match"; else echo "The strings do *not* match"; fi
dash: 1: [: foo: unexpected operator
The strings do *not* match
```

Solution: switch to `=`

```
$ if [ foo = foo ]; then echo "The strings match"; else echo "The strings do *not* match"; fi
The strings match
```

If you're going to use `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`, you really need to watch out for bashisms. There's a good page on this in [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). Either that, or switch to /bin/bash.

P.s. If you're going to use bash extensions, I'd recommend using `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` for conditionals -- it fixes most of the syntactic oddities of `[ ]`, and adds some useful new capabilities like pattern and regular expression matching.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely, I think you got your redirection output wrong on line 4.

Must be :

```
echo "we are suspending at $(date)..." >> /home/albin/stuff/suspend_test
```

instead of

```
echo "we are suspending at $(date)..." > /home/albin/stuff/suspend_test
```

Also, I think $1 is neither equal to 'pre' or 'post'. From looking at the output you posted, I can't understand from why these strings **"tis"** and **"ons"** have come from.

Comment: "tis" and "ons" are abbreviations for "Tuesday" and "Wednesday" in Swedish

Answer (score 0):

Probably caller of this script passing you other arguments than post or pre. 
Change log writing to use >> instead of > (to prevent overwriting log all time) and try add echo “${1}” >> log at first line, then you can see what arguments you got in your script